# Why does compiler allow out-of-bounds array access even with constexpr index?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, constexpr, c++17

For example if we have an `std::array` and we instantiate an element that is out of bound using `constexpr` the compiler wouldn't report error:

```
constexpr int EvaluateSpecialArrayIndex(int a)
{ return a * sizeof(int); }

array<int, 5> arr;

cout << arr[98] << endl; //compiles fine

cout << arr[EvaluateSpecialArrayIndex(4)] << endl; //the same as above
```

Can't we restrict this somehow?

Comment: note: the standard doesn't permit for `arr[n]` to be rejected, because UB is not caused until execution reaches that point; e.g. this code might be in a function that ends up never being called.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It may be [not as simple as that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23153445/11683).

Comment: @GSerg UB can time travel once it's hit, but not if it isn't hit  (sounds paradoxical at first but actually isn't, as the first answer indicates).  I guess you could argue that if the code path is guaranteed to hit `arr[98]` then the UB could time-travel back to the compilation stage

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To ensure that `constexpr` functions are evaluated at compile time, you must force them to be by making their result `constexpr`.  For example:

```
#include <array>

int
main()
{
    constexpr std::array<int, 5> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int i = arr[6];  // run time error
}
```

However:

```
#include <array>

int
main()
{
    constexpr std::array<int, 5> arr{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    constexpr int i = arr[6];  // compile time error
}
```

Unfortunately, for this to actually work, `std::array` must conform to the C++14 specification, not the C++11 specification.  As the C++11 specification does not mark the `const` overload of `std::array::operator[]` with `constexpr`.

So in C++11 you're out of luck.  In C++14, you can make it work, but only if both the `array` and the result of calling the index operator are declared `constexpr`.

**Clarification**

The C++11 specification for array indexing reads:

```
                reference operator[](size_type n);
          const_reference operator[](size_type n) const;
```

And the C++14 specification for array indexing reads:

```
                reference operator[](size_type n);
constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type n) const;
```

I.e. `constexpr` was added to the `const` overload for C++14.

**Update**

And the C++17 specification for array indexing reads:

```
constexpr       reference operator[](size_type n);
constexpr const_reference operator[](size_type n) const;
```

The cycle is now complete.  The universe can be computed at compile-time. ;-)

Comment: The meaning of `constexpr` without `const` changed from C++11 to 14.

Comment: So, the non-`const`ness of the `operator[]` in `std::array` that is `constexpr` has no impact in C++11.  It was added in C++14 because of the change of meaning, and the ability to mutate data in `constexpr` expressions meaning that non-`const` `constexpr` now means it is non-`const` yet `constexpr`.

Comment: @Yakk: So my clarification is an attempt to clarify that the index operators from C++11 were not decorated with `constexpr`.  And `constexpr` was added only to the `const` overload in C++14.  The C++14 language changes for `constexpr` did not have an impact here.

Comment: Strange how this one was implemented, as 'constexpr' functions can't do 'static_assert' on parameters.

Comment: I also believe that this is for compile-time evaluated arrays only, am I right?

Answer (score 8):

If you know the array index at compile time, you could use `std::get` with an index, and that *will* cause a compilation failure if you're out of bounds

```
std::array<int, 4> a{{1,2,3,4}};
std::get<4>(a); // out of bounds, fails to compile
```

The error I get from gcc-4.9 ends with:

```
error: static assertion failed: index is out of bounds
       static_assert(_Int < _Nm, "index is out of bounds");
```

`std::get` only works with constant expression indices (the index is a template argument), so with `std::array` it can always detect out-of-bounds at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

Array access on an `std::array` is the same for a regular C-array, it never checks to see if the index is valid, it just invokes UB if it's out of range. If you want restrictions, use [`std::array::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at) which throws an `std::out_of_range()` exception for values that exceed the array bounds.

```
arr.at(EvaluateSpecialArrayIndex(4)); // terminate called after throwing
                                      // an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
```

If you want a compile-time error use `std::get`:

```
std::get<EvaluateSpecialArrayIndex(4)>(arr); // error: static_assert failed
                                             // "index is out of bounds"
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb There's a `constexpr` version of `at()` in C++14, but maybe he's not using that standard.

Comment: @Matt `std::get` is overloaded for `std::array`. That's compile-time. See Ryan's answer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yeah, you're right. `std::get` is another option though.

Comment: And what if it is a 'constexpr', still the error is thrown at run-time. Very nice with using templates - but I also want to put lvalues as indexes.

Comment: From what I undestand, if `arr` is an array of static or automatic duration, `arr+x-arr` is `constexpr` (equal to `x`) if `x` is `constexpr` and `x` is no larger than the length (number of elements) of `arr`.  Will it be regarded as not being `constexpr` if `x` exceeds the length of `arr`?

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer, because it would be very costly for `std::array` to have separate `constexpr` overloads to check for this sort of thing. If you want, you can write your own wrapper around `std::array` that offers a compile-checked access for compile time constants. Something like:

```
template<typename T, size_t S>
class safeArray
{
    std::array<T, S> m_arr;
    public:
    template<size_t A>
    T& safeAt() { 
        static_assert(A < S, "Index out of bounds");
        return m_arr[A]; 
    }
    // other funcs as needed
};
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
safeArray<int, 5> arr;
cout << arr.safeAt<98>() << endl; // compile error
```

This can generate a lot of functions, however. Most of the time, if your design is sound, you won't ever need this type of check.

Comment: If you wind up in a dependent scope where you have `safeArray<T, 5> arr` you'd need to call it as `arr.template safeAt<98>()` fyi.  That's why `std::get` is a free function