# Why doesn't 'd /= d' throw a division by zero exception when d == 0?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior, division, divide-by-zero

I don't quite understand why I don't get a division by zero exception:

```cpp
int d = 0;
d /= d;
```

I expected to get a division by zero exception but instead `d == 1`.

Why doesn't `d /= d` throw a division by zero exception when `d == 0`?

Comment: its a matter of definition what should be the result of `0/0`. I don't know what the c++ standard says, but I am not aware of any case were you get an exception thrown without explicitly asking for

Comment: That’s undefined behavior.

Comment: There's no such thing as a division by zero exception.

Comment: To clarify some of the comments: when you see a message about a "division by zero exception" that's the operating system telling you that something went wrong. It is **not** a C++ exception. In C++, exceptions are thrown by a `throw` statement. Nothing else (unless you're in undefined-behavior land).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: The "zero division error" is an interruption that some CPU define and can be trapped, but it's not always the case. That's why it's an undefined behavior : it completely depends on the target.

Comment: There's no such thing as "_division by zero exception._" in C++.

Comment: possible duplciate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745311/c-division-by-0

Comment: @OP What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Adrian I have used `g++ 8.3.0` to get the aforementioned result.

Comment: Note that on my environment (clang on macOS), the program crashes with a floating-point exception when compiled with no optimizations, and does nothing when compiled with `-O1` (using whatever gibberish was sitting in the register)

Comment: @user11659763 _"That's why it's an undefined behavior : it completely depends on the target."_ - That's not what undefined behaviour means _at all_; what you're describing is [implementation-defined behaviour](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/C_language:Terms:Implementation-defined_behaviour). Undefined behaviour is a much, much stronger statement.

Comment: As usual, the answer is "volatile"

Comment: `8.5.5 Multiplicative operators` -> `The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary % operator yields the remainder from the division
of the first expression by the second. If the second operand of / or % is zero the behavior is undefined.` (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

C++ does not have a "Division by Zero" Exception to catch. The behavior you're observing is the result of Compiler optimizations:

1. The compiler assumes Undefined Behavior doesn't happen
2. Division by Zero in C++ is undefined behavior
3. Therefore, code which *can* cause a Division by Zero is presumed to not do so.

   - And, code which *must* cause a Division by Zero is presumed to never happen
4. Therefore, the compiler deduces that because Undefined Behavior doesn't happen, then the conditions for Undefined Behavior in this code (`d == 0`) must not happen
5. Therefore, `d / d` must always equal 1.

#### However...

We can force the compiler to trigger a "real" division by zero with a minor tweak to your code.

```
volatile int d = 0;
d /= d; //What happens?
```

So now the question remains: now that we've basically forced the compiler to allow this to happen, what happens? It's undefined behavior—but we've now prevented the compiler from optimizing around this undefined behavior.

Mostly, it depends on the target environment. This will not trigger a software exception, but it *can* (depending on the target CPU) trigger a Hardware Exception (an Integer-Divide-by-Zero), which cannot be caught in the traditional manner a software exception can be caught. This is definitely the case for an x86 CPU, and most other (but not all!) architectures.

There are, however, methods of dealing with the hardware exception (if it occurs) instead of just letting the program crash: look at this post for some methods that might be applicable: [Catching exception: divide by zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25601100/5241642). Note they vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: With or without the 'volatile', a run with MSVC/VS-2019 gives: exited with code -1073741676!

Comment: … switching to clang-cl, though, I get a 'random' value for `d` (nearly always 14684554) but no crash??

Comment: @Adrian Both of those are perfectly ok since the behaviour is undefined. Literally *anything* is OK.

Comment: "Division by Zero in C++ is undefined behavior" -> note that the compiler can't make this optimisation for floating point types under IEE754. It must set d to NaN.

Comment: @Adrian if i understand the answer correctly, thats the whole point of it. When you got `1` as result this was due to the compiler realizing that `d /= d;` is either `1` or UB. UB cannot happen in correct code, so it must be `1`. If the compiler doesnt do this optimization anything can happen (aka UB)

Comment: Interestingly this optimisation only occurs in gcc when d is an int, not when it's a double: https://godbolt.org/z/XeFAAA

Comment: @RichardHodges a compiler operating under IEEE754 is not allowed to make the optimisation for a double: NaN must be produced.

Comment: @Bathsheba: This is wrong. IEEE754 states _"seven invalid arithmetic operations
shall deliver a NaN unless they are trapped"_. Which means that it is very much possible, and legitimate not to deliver a Nan". The optimization is therefore certainly allowed **unless** the compiler explicitly disabled floating point exceptions or is otherwise certain that the hardware doesn't support/deliver them.

Comment: @formerlyknownas: It's not a matter of "optimizing away the UB" -- it's still the case that "anything can happen"; it's just that producing `1` is a perfectly valid anything. Getting 14684554 must be because the compiler optimizes _even further_ -- it propagates the initial `d==0` condition and can therefore conclude not only "this is either 1 or UB" but in fact "this is UB, period". Therefore it doesn't even bother to produce code that loads the constant `1`.

Comment: Specifically for x86 (signal) vs. ARM (no signal), and how/why the x86 hardware exception turns into a POSIX SIGFPE in the case where we do get division overflow, see [Why does integer division by -1 (negative one) result in FPE?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46378104)

Comment: BTW, the reason you need `volatile` even with "optimization disabled" is that GCC `-O0` does still optimize some *within* a single expression.  But `volatile` tells it that each read of `d` is separate and can't be assumed to give the same value.

Comment: I wonder why volatile case is not optimized. Of course you need a read and a write, but why not compile it to(read d, write 1)

Comment: @RiaD as Peter just said - the compiler needs to issue two reads and one write (each side of the division), and each read might return a different value.

Comment: People are always suggesting volatile to prevent optimization, but what constitutes a volatile read or write is implementation-defined.

Comment: @RonJohn Well, `X/X = 1` for every X except 0 - for which it is undefined. In undefined behavior **any** result is a "correct" result, because being undefined means that there are no rules for right or wrong. So the compiler could generate standard compliant code that said: `if (X != 0) result = 1 else format hard drive and destroy computer`. Or it could just shorten all of that (and be a bit nicer to OP's computer) and just generate code that returns 1 always.

Comment: @Frodyne if that's what "undefined" means, and if they let 0/0 be undefined (as opposed to causing an error, or letting the h/w throw an error) then the WG21 committee should commit mass hari kari.

Comment: @RonJohn Undefined is not a value, it's a behavior. C++ code that includes a division by zero is wrong, according to the standard, so the compiler doesn't care what it gets set to. Whether that's 1, 0, some random number, or the program just crashes - they're all correct as defined by the standard.

Comment: Worth emphasising, the compiler can do *anything*. It could make a program that hires criminals to kidnap your loved ones & post you a ransom letter and it would still be correct by the standard, as far as I know. Of course, it probably wouldn’t be a very popular compiler...

Comment: with gcc I am getting the same result i.e. d == 1 even if I disable optimization using -O0 switch. With macOS compiler I am getting floating point exception.

Comment: @Jangid Certain optimizations have to be disabled with specific flags, not just through `-O0`. It's like Copy Ellision, which will usually get performed even when optimizations are disabled. I don't know which flag specifically (if any) control optimizations around this behavior.

Answer (score 39):

Just to complement the other answers, the fact that division by zero is undefined behavior means that *the compiler is free to do anything* in cases where it would happen:

- The compiler may assume that `0 / 0 == 1` and optimize accordingly.  That's effectively what it appears to have done here.
- The compiler could also, if it wanted to, assume that `0 / 0 == 42` and set `d` to that value.
- The compiler could also decide that the value of `d` is indeterminate, and thus leave the variable uninitialized, so that its value will be whatever happened to be previously written into the memory allocated for it.  Some of the unexpected values observed on other compilers in the comments may be caused by those compilers doing something like this.
- The compiler may also decide to abort the program or raise an exception whenever a division by zero occurs.  Since, for this program, the compiler can determine that this will *always* happen, it can simply emit the code to raise the exception (or abort execution entirely) and treat the rest of the function as unreachable code.
- Instead of raising an exception when division by zero occurs, the compiler could also choose to stop the program and start a game of Solitaire instead.  That also falls under the umbrella of "undefined behavior".
- In principle, the compiler could even issue code that *caused the computer to explode* whenever a division by zero occurs.  There is nothing in the C++ standard that would forbid this.  (For certain kinds of applications, like a missile flight controller, this might even be considered a desirable safety feature!)
- Furthermore, the standard [explicitly allows undefined behavior to "time travel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914788/at-what-point-in-the-loop-does-integer-overflow-become-undefined-behavior), so that the compiler may also do any of the things above (or anything else) *before* the division by zero happens.  Basically, the standard allows the compiler to freely reorder operations as long as the observable behavior of the program is not changed — but even that last requirement is explicitly waived if executing the program would result in undefined behavior.  So, in effect, the *entire* behavior of any program execution that would, at some point, trigger undefined behavior is undefined!
- As a consequence of the above, the compiler may also simply *assume that undefined behavior does not happen*, since one permissible behavior for a program that would behave in an undefined manner on some inputs is for it to simply behave *as if the input had been something else*.  That is, even if the original value of `d` was not known at compile time, the compiler could still assume that it's never zero and optimize the code accordingly.  In the particular case of the OP's code, this is effectively indistinguishable from the compiler just assuming that `0 / 0 == 1`, but the compiler could also, for example, assume that the `puts()` in `if (d == 0) puts("About to divide by zero!"); d /= d;` never gets executed!

Answer (score 31):

The behaviour of integer division by zero is undefined by the C++ standard. It is **not** required to throw an exception.

(Floating point division by zero is also undefined but IEEE754 defines it.)

Your compiler is optimising `d /= d` to, effectively `d = 1` which is a reasonable choice to make. It's allowed to make this optimisation since it's allowed to assume there is no undefined behaviour in your code - that is `d` cannot possibly be zero.

Comment: It's important to be extra clear, that also something else could happen, IOW this behavior can't be relied on.

Comment: I think simply emphasizing "You compiler" would be enough.

Comment: When you say it's reasonable for the compiler to assume "that is `d` cannot possibly be zero," do you also assume that the compiler doesn't see the line: `int d = 0;` ?? :)

Comment: Compiler sees it, but probably doesn't care. The extra code complexity required in the already crazy complex compiler for an edge case like this probably isn't worth it.

Comment: @user4581301 Taking both together allows it to detect a poisoned branch, allowing it to prune much more code. So it would be useful.

Comment: @Adrian absolutely. Undefined behaviour applies backwards as well as forwards. At the point d /= d is reached, it can assume d is never zero.

Comment: So if you wrote "int d = 0; if (d == 0) printf("d = zero\n"); d /= d; " the compiler can remove the printf as well.

Comment: @gnasher729 The compiler can remove all the code on that branch.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to understand what happens is to see the assembly output

```
int divide(int num) {
    return num/num;
}
```

will generate for x86-64

```
divide(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     eax, 1
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

As you can see there are no divide operations here,
but we have `mov     eax, 1`.

Here is a link to reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/MbY6Wqh4T

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can have your code generate a C++ exception in this (and other cases) by using boost safe numerics. https://github.com/boostorg/safe_numerics